# Where does 'Krypton' fit in the DCEU?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, canon, krypton-2018

The upcoming and highly anticipated mini-series [*Krypton*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4276624) is due to be released in 2018. Now from the recent [trailer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4276624/videoplayer/vi334673945?ref_=tt_ov_vi), we can see that the set design looks very similar to the Krypton shown in Zack Snyder's [*Man of Steel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_of_Steel_(film)), and they seem to be alluding to how the two are in a shared universe. However, the show is produced by the [SyFy Channel](http://www.syfy.com/krypton) and you can see in the 0:45 mark that someone hands the 'old' version of Superman's uniform to an ancestor of Kal El:

This is confusing and seems like they're trying to avoid a cross-over (most likely due to licencing reasons). I just need clarification, **is there an official statement on where *Krypton* fits in with the DCEU?**

Answer (score 9):

There is, Geoff Johns (Chief Creative Officer of DC Comics and the producer and writer of the TV shows) said:

> '...it will stand on its own and exist in its own universe.'

Consequently, there won't be crossovers with other shows set in the DCEU.

He also mentions

> 'it's about a conspiracy that has traveled back in time to prevent
>   Superman's legacy from ever happening'

which would explain the 'old' version of Superman's uniform in the trailer.

Quotes from [this Hollywood Reporter article](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/krypton-panel-brainiac-adam-strange-hawkwoman-comic-con-2017-1023589).